# How to add column with dates by using Corpus.slice

Tags: python, export, networkx, tethne

I'm really new in programming, that's why my question can be probably boring or stupid, sorry for this! I'm trying to build co-authorship graph in Gephi (*graphml format*). Everything is fine, but I don't understand, how to import dates in the same file. My code is following:

```
from tethne.readers import wos
MyCorpus = wos.corpus_from_dir(datapath)
from tethne.networks import authors
ca_graph = authors.coauthors(MyCorpus.all_papers())
from tethne.writers import graph
graph.to_graphml(ca_graph, './file.graphml')`
```

So, in this **file.graphml** I have **authors** and **institutions**, but I don't have any **years** (when this work was published). I have found a piece of code [here](http://diging.github.io/tethne/doc/0.6.1-beta/tutorial.coauthors.html#building-a-graphcollection)

```
MyCorpus.slice('date', 'time_period', window_size=1, cumulative=True)
```

but I have no idea, how to write everything in one file. I will appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tethne.writers.graph` uses `networkx` graphs your problem boils down to [writing attributes to networkx nodes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#node-attributes)

You could try something like:

```
for author, attribs in ca_graph:
    # somehow calculate a year_value
    ca_graph.node[author]['year'] = year_value
```